# I can't sign and distribute an iOS app if I haven't an iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Apple Developer account and an iOS app's source code, but I can't fix this error:
"No Devices Registered
Creating a provisioning profile requires one or more devices to be registered with your team.  Connect a device to your Mac to add it to your team."

[image: no devices registered]

What can I do for signing and distributing the app without an iPhone, in this case?

Comment: How have you tested your app without an iOS device? The simulator is not enough.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone or a iDevice. @rmaddy

Comment: Right. That's why I asked how you have tested your app. You need to test on a real device.

Comment: Even if you can't afford one, you can't really develop without one, and especially can't distribute or release an app without testing. Try and get the oldest and cheapest you can afford (provided its not too old that new versions of IOS won't install on it). If you really have no money and can't borrow a phone there are web sites that have devices available where you can remotely use them.

Comment: It's this fact documented somewhere? @rmaddy

Comment: It is in the documentation @Silviu

Comment: For more info: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood

Comment: And if I use a remote device, even I think I will buy a iPhone 5S probably, how can this remote device will help me to solve my problem with xCode? Or they will sign the app in my place? Thanks, @MartinH

Comment: Because you would register the device's UUID on your provisioning portal and provisioning profiles. The message says "Creating a provisioning profile requires one or more devices to be registered with your team". You do not need to connect the device to do that, just need the UUID.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinH! I understand all aspects now. Regards!

Comment: You could google a valid UDID and register that.